# Update an array element in React Hookstate

Tags: reactjs

I have an application using React Hookstate.
For one state I am using an Array. I want to update a single element in this array.
But the updated element always is wrapped inside a proxy tag.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState, none, State } from '@hookstate/core';

const Test: React.FC = () => {
 const books: State<Array<any>> = useState([
   'Harry Potter',
   'Sherlock Holmes',
   'Swiss Family Robinson',
   'Tarzon',
 ]);
 const SwapItems = () => {
   // books.merge((p) => ({ 1: p[0], 0: p[1] })); // this way it works.

   const reOrderedItem = books.nested(0);
   books.nested(0).set(none);
   books.set((p) => {
     p.splice(0, 0, reOrderedItem);
     return p;
   });
 };

 return (
   <div>
     <ol>
       {books.map((book) => {
         return <li>{book.get()}</li>;
       })}
     </ol>
     <br />
     <button onClick={SwapItems}>Swap Books</button>
   </div>
 );
};

export default Test;
```

//error
react-dom.development.js:11393 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you just need to add `.value` as follows:

```js
const reOrderedItem = books.nested(0).value;
```

I'm not sure why you don't prefer the `update` version that works though -- that seems much simpler.

Alternatively, if you want to use `set`, why not work with the items directly?

```js
   const reOrderedItem = books.nested(0).value;
   books.nested(0).set(books.nested(1).value);
   books.nested(1).set(reOrderedItem);
```

Alternatively, you could do the manipulation inside `set` like so (but you're right that this is inefficient for large arrays):

```js
const SwapItems = () => {
  books.set((p) => {
    const [a, b, ...rest] = p;
    return [b, a, ...rest];
  });
};
```

Comment: I am using React Hookstate. Official documentation suggests not to use spreadings with ...
Refer https://hookstate.js.org/docs/nested-state/#adding-a-new-property. 
Also tried the `nested(0).value`. But it also didn't work.

Comment: Good point. I've added another version that uses `set` which you could try.

Comment: Author oh Hookstate is here. The spreading, 2 set calls will do the job. The best way is to use merge call. Here is the code sample and docs on how to swap two elements: https://hookstate.js.org/docs/nested-state/#swapping-two-elements

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I wanted to reorder a certain item on the list.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState, State } from '@hookstate/core';

const Test: React.FC = () => {
  const books: State<Array<any>> = useState([
    'Harry Potter',
    'Sherlock Holmes',
    'Swiss Family Robinson',
    'Tarzon',
  ]);
  const ReorderItems = () => {
    books.set((p) => {
      const reOrderedItem = p[2];
      p.splice(2, 1);
      p.splice(0, 0, reOrderedItem);
      return p;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ol>
        {books.map((book) => {
          return <li>{book.get()}</li>;
        })}
      </ol>
      <br />
      <button onClick={ReorderItems}>Swap Books</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```